# jhbuild will not continue git downloads

Tags: 10.10, git

I have been trying to install gnome 3 on my 10.10. I read this tutorial and am using jhbuild to install the 41 required packages. jhbuild apparently pulls the required packages using git and wget. I have been experiencing awful internet connectivity for the past couple of months. I have complained, but my ISP does not really bother, plus I don't get time to bother.

The point is whenever jhbuild comes around to pull down gtk+ 3.0(or some other package) using git, my internet connectivity goes down long enough to get a

```
From 192.168.1.1 icmp_seq=1130 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.1 icmp_seq=1131 Destination Host Unreachable
```

It invariably comes up after a few such lines, however jhbuild refuses to continue. I either have to manually restart the phase or wait till jhbuild returns an error. In both cases jhbuild starts downloading the files from scratch for that particular package. Does git not support download resuming?

Plus, I have installed gtk+ 3.0.9(the latest stable release), but jhbuild still starts downloading gtk+ 3.0 using git. Should I download the [unstable release](http://www.gtk.org/download.html) using git?

This is what I often end up with

```
*** Checking out gtk3 *** [8/41]
git clone git://git.gnome.org/gtk+ gtk3
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/abc/gnome-shell/source/gtk3/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 270771, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (41632/41632), done.
^C*** Error during phase checkout of gtk3: ########## Error running git clone git://git.gnome.org/gtk+ gtk3 *** [8/41]

  [1] Rerun phase checkout
  [2] Ignore error and continue to configure
  [3] Give up on module
  [4] Start shell
  [5] Reload configuration
  [6] Go to phase "wipe directory and start over"
choice: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Git` does not support a way to continue an interrupted cloning. You need to start from scratch. So, what can you do if your Internet connection is in a mess?

If you can get someone to create a .tar.bz of the clone, you can download using `wget -c` and then extract on your computer. It is fine even if this is a rather old clone; you or jhbuild can perform a `git pull --rebase` to that your clone will get updated, which is quite fast.